# Does python use the best possible algorithms in order to save the most time it can?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a question that might be very simple to answer. 
I couldn't find the answer anywhere.
Does python use the best possible algorithms in order to save the most time it can?
I just saw on some website that for example, the **max** method time order -in lists- is O(n) in python which there are better time orders as you know.
Is it true?
should I use the algorithms that I know they can perform better in order to save more time or does python did this for me in its methods?

Comment: For a general use case, I don't think there would be better than O(n) for `max`. The best you'll get is it may be implemented in C, in which case it'll have the same complexity, but will be faster.

Comment: If you don't have any additional information about elements in the list then the best you can get is O(n) by iterating through elements of the list. You can get better times if your list is sorted, for example. But then you need to use a different method. For example for `max` in a sorted list you just need to get the list's last element. Python cannot and will not do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> max method time order -in lists- is O(n) in python which there are better time orders as you know. Is it true?

No this is not true. Finding the maximum value in a list will require that *all* values in the list are inspected, hence *O(n)*.

You may be confused with lists that have been *prepared* in some way. For instance:

- You have a list that is *already sorted* (which is a *O(nlogn)* process). In that case you can of course get the maximum in constant time, since you know its index. If the list is sorted in ascending order, it would be unwise to call `max` on it, as that would indeed be a waste of time. *You* may know the list is sorted, but python will not assume this, and still scan the whole list.
- You have a list that has been *heapified* to a max-heap (which is a *O(n)* process). Again, in that case you can get the maximum in constant time, since it is stored at index 0. Lists can be heapified with `heapq` -- the default being a min-heap.

So, if you know nothing about your list, then you will have to inspect *all* values to be sure to identify the maximum. That is what `max()` does. In case you *do* know something more that could help to identify the maximum without having to look at *all* values, then use another, more appropriate method.

> should I use the algorithms that I know they can perform better in order to save more time or does python did this for me in its methods?

You should use the algorithms that you know can perform better (based on what you know about a data structure). In many cases there is such better algorithm implementation available via a python library. For example, to find a particular value in a *sorted* list, use `bisect.bisect_left` and not `index`.

Look at a more complex example. Say you have written code that can generate chess moves and simulate a game of chess. You have good ideas about evaluation functions, alphabeta pruning, killer moves, lookup tables, ...and a bunch of other optimisation techniques. You cannot expect python to get smart when you issue a naive `max` on "all" evaluated chess states. You need to implement the complex algorithm to efficiently search and filter the right states to get the "best" chess move out of that forest of information without wasting time on less promising moves.

Answer (score 0):

A Python list is a sequential and contiguus container. That means that finding the ith element is in constant time, and adding to the end is easy is no reallocation is required.

Finding a value is O(n/2), and finding min or max is O(n).

If you want a list and being able to find its minimum value in O(1), the `heapq` module that maintains a binary tree is available.

But Python offers few specialized containers in its standard library.

Comment: O(n/2) is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of complexity, you'll find that python almost always uses solutions based on algorithms with best complexity. Performance may vary depending on constants, and python is just not the fastest language compared to C or C++.

In this case, if you're looking for max value from a list, there is no better solution - to find maximum value, you have to check every value, meaning solution is O(n). That's just how lists work - it's just list with values. If you were to use some other structure, e.g. sorted list - accessing max value would take O(1) - but you would pay for this low complexity with higher complexity of adding/deleting values.

Answer (score -1):

It differs from library to library

The defult python librarys like the sort function (if a algorithem not selected) will use the most efficient algorithem by deffult.

Sadly is Python quite slow in genera compared to languages like C, C++ or java.

This is becouse that python is one script that reads your script and executes it live.

C, C++ and Java all compiles to binary (exe) before executing.

## //SW

Comment: Java doesn´t get compiled to binary, it compiles to bytecode which is executed by the JVM.